# SSIS ODBC compatibility issue

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which is using ODBC source to connect to Impala. My problem is exactly same described in this question.
[SSIS Package Works in VS but not in SSIS because of ODBC Data Flow Task Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52545716/ssis-package-works-in-vs-but-not-in-ssis-because-of-odbc-data-flow-task-error)

I tried the solution but didn't work.

I used VS 2017 to build project. my server has SQL server 2016. I tried deployment by changing deployment target to 2016 as given in the solution but it's not working.

I tried all the answers found over internet nothing worked.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server? Did you try forcing the runtime to use 32 bit? Are both 32 bit and 64 bit drivers installed on your server? Does your error also mention Attunity?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I'm voting to close your comment for being too broad. Please edit the comment to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to allow the OP to identify an adequate response. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this comment. :P

Comment: I'm not sure if you're serious.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sorry for the confusion. The :P was meant to signify tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: Turns out _i’m_ too serious :p

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have SQL server 2017 in my machine. server has 2016. yes I tried forcing the runtime 32 bit. Yes both 32 and 64 bit drivers installed on server. Yes error has Attunity.

Comment: This kind of error is usually down to a mismatch between versions or deploying to an Express edition (that's why I was after the serve edition - Express, Standard, Developer, Enterprise). It's unlikely your server is Express edition though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many options finally I was able to fix the issue. Server had SQL server 2016 installed. I built project in Visual studio 2017 and had set configuration property "TargetServerVersion" of my project to "SQL server 2016". I was using SSMS 2017 for deployment of my package.

1. Uninstalled Visual studio 2017 and SSMS 2017 from my machine.
2. Installed Visual studio 2015, business intelligent for VS 2015  and SSMS 2016.
3. Create new SSIS project in visual studio 2015.
4. Set the "TargetServerVersion" property to SQL server 2016.
5. Deployment package using SSMS 2016.

it worked.

what I learnt is that setting "TargetServerVersion" property is not enough. SSMS version which you use for deployment should be same as target server version.